# Accessing text of all td text using jquery in an application

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

Hi I want to access text present in all  section of my application. I cannot use id because in one application there are different tables with different id's. I want to access text name whenever I place mouse on that td cell irrespective of table so I can't use id. Please suggest me a way to do this using JQuery. The  text which I want to access are from asp.net aspx page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In jquery, you can apply a hover event to every td which fetches it's text. put the text in a variable, then pass it on to your .aspx handler with ajax. here is a simple example. its a good idea to put this script block in your ready function, or near the end of your document.

jQuery

```
$('td').hover(function () {
        //mouse over

        //get the data
        var tdText = $(this).text();
        console.log(tdText);

        //do something with the data

        var jqxhr = $.ajax("handler.aspx?text=" + tdText)
            .done(function () {
                console.log("success");

                //do something
            })
            .fail(function () {
                console.log("error");

                //do something else
            });
    },

    function () {
        //mouse out
        console.log("mouse-out");
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I can only help you with determining if the mouse cursor is above any td element. You will need to modify the code to fit your needs to display something useful.

**HTML:**

```
<p id="message">&nbsp;</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Data 1</td>
        <td>Data 2</td>
        <td>Data 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data A</td>
        <td>Data B</td>
        <td>Data C</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JS:**

```
addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) {
    if (event.toElement.localName == 'td')
        $('#message').html("You are in a table cell");
    else
        $('#message').html("&nbsp;");
}, false);
```

I also created a fiddle for you to test: http://jsfiddle.net/m3EmK/

Comment: This is cool. I've only done event listening in jquery like my answer above, I like your pure JavaScript implementation.